# Android Bottom Appbar Fab transition animation disappears when replacing the menu or using setSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, animation, bottomappbar

I'm using `BottomAppBar` with `Floating Action Button`, when ever i navigate between two `fragments` using `Floating Action Button` and use 
`bottomAppbar.replaceMenu()` or use `setSupportActionBar(bottomAppbar)` the animation of the `Floating Action Button`disappears, how can I fix the problem?